# Cannot zip directory from within R without including full file path

Tags: r, zip

I have a directory of output from an R script (pdf, csv files) which I would like to zip (zip from utils package) each time the code is run.

```
>path_out
I:\\full\\path\\to\\file\\
>files2zip <- dir(path_out, full.names = TRUE)
>zip(zipfile = paste(path_out,unitList[ii],"_",Sys.Date(),sep=""), files  = files2zip)
```

This painfully generates a zip file with the full path directory included in the file:

```
>unzip(zipfile = paste(path_out,unitList[ii],"_",Sys.Date(),".zip",sep=""), list = TRUE, junkpaths = FALSE)
                                            Date
/full/path/to/file/file1.pdf   7978       2018-04-16 13:44:00
/full/path/to/file/file2.pdf    6665      2018-04-16 09:14:00
/full/path/to/file/file3.pdf   6557       2018-04-15 11:22:00
/full/path/to/file/file4.csv    627       2018-03-27 11:10:00
```

In Bash zip there is a -j tag which junks the full path and only includes relative paths. Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `extras` parameter of the `zip()` function.

So:

```
zip(zipfile = paste(path_out,unitList[ii],"_",Sys.Date(),sep=""), files  = files2zip, extras = '-j')
```

Comment: Thanks, it's also works fine with `-j` in the flags arguments :  `flags = '-j'`